# Memory failure on DIMM2 Dell T3500

Tags: memory, bios, hardware-failure

I'm having troubles with my DELL T3500.  It has:

- a w5590 3.33 GHz 4c/8t
- 12 GB (3 × 4 GB) RAM DDR3 1333 MHz

I get the message `Memory failure on DIMM2 Dell T3500` when I turn on my computer and it starts to boot up. 
I continuously hit <kbd>F1</kbd> to continue so I could use my PC but now it shows in the Task Manager only 8 GB available.

How can I fix it? I already switched the RAM between slots something like 5 or 6 times. It always says DIMM2 regardless what I change.

Comment: Seems like a hardware problem. Ensure that the DIMM slot is clean. I once had to use a pencil eraser to clean the contacts on the base of the RAM sticks when I had a RAM problem (which might not be your problem).

Comment: @harrymc, pencil eraser isn't exactly the tool that professionals would use to clean their RAM stick contacts with. No offence :) Although, it might work.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen: One uses the tools at hand. I agree that this isn't the best tool for the job and was rather surprised that it worked. I don't recommend it, of course.

Comment: @harrymc, yes absolutely, I agree 100%. OP, can you run memory diagnostics or does it even show the third RAM stick?

Comment: Given that OP ends ip with 8G working (2 out of 3) I would assume three are seen and one is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [Xeon W5590](https://ark.intel.com/products/41643/Intel-Xeon-Processor-W5590-8M-Cache-3-33-GHz-6-40-GT-s-Intel-QPI-?q=w5590) CPU which uses triple channel memory. That means it can utilize 3 banks of memory at the same time for higher performance. For this reason your system also comes equipped with 3 memory modules (DDR3, 667MHz)

When your system powers on its firmware (either BIOS or UEFI in a PC) determines how much memory is present. Usually it also checks the memory.

During this check it discovered errors when accessing the DIMM in bank2. This can have multiple causes, but the most likely ones are:

- A broken memory controller (which is part of the CPU since the Nehelam series, and your CPU is a Nehelam based Xeon),
- Broken path between the memory controller and the DIMM socket (which can include dirt between the contacts)
- A broken DIMM connector (motherboard side)
- Or a broken DIMM.

Your firmware detected three 4GB DIMMs. One faulty. It made the choice of using both working DIMMs and ignoring the third, which is why you now have 2x4GB to work with.

Now to fixing this:

Since you already moved the DIMMs around and always got the same error we can assume that it is not the DIMM itself. That leaves the memory controller and the physical path between the memory controller and the DIMM.

If it is dirt then you are lucky, Cleaning the contacts might help.

If it is the motherboard then best you can do is try different configurations.   Most Nehelam boards come with 6 DIMM sockets, and their layout might be described as:
Dimm 1 on channel 1A
Dimm 2 on channel 1B
Dimm 3 on channel 1C
Dimm 4 on channel 2A
Dimm 5 on channel 2B
Dimm 6 on channel 3C

Memory will usually be in the socket corresponding to 1A,1B and 1C, alloing all the memory parts to be used simultaneously. But 1A, 1C, 2B etc also may work.

*May* since the only Nehelam boards I owned only supported very specific memory fill sequences.

If it is the memory controller then there is nothing you can do short of replacing it. And since it is part of the CPU that means replacing the whole CPU.

Comment: Dell actually has a page listing the possible memory configurations for the T3500:
https://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/sln288863/precision-workstation-t3500-memory-specifications-and-configurations?lang=en They list the 3 first slots or all six slots as possible configuration for 4 GB RAM modules.

Comment: This can't be a problem with the CPU, which by the documentation can support up to 144 GB. It's surely a motherboard limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked for me:

1. Remove all RAMs from your slots.
2. Put a single RAM in Dimm 1, then open the PC, and check if the message disappeared, then power off the PC.
3. Put the second RAM in Dimm 2, then do as step 1, and so on with all the left RAMs, you should put the RAMs in the right order (Dimm1, Dimm2, Dimm3,.. etc.).